# How to make deleted record as false on the table in SQL Server using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a `ward table` and it contains columns like `wardid, wmemname, isActive,` and so on... `wardid` is the primary key and `isActive` is boolean.

If the user deletes the record from the front end, I set `isActive` to false.

> "Record is deleted successfully"

This message is shown to the user.

In my delete procedure I wrote an `update` statement to make `isActive` set to false:

```
update wardtable 
set isActive = false 
where wardid = @wardid
```

Fine up to here. In case the user wants to enter the details with the deleted `wardid`, now there is a problem with a primary key violation message from the front end when he tries to enter the data with the deleted `wardid`.

How to solve this issue?

Suppose if I take another id in my `ward table` then, it allows if I make id as an `autoincrement`. But duplicate `wardid's` are allowed in my `ward table` if I do like that.

So, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: I think Deleted wards should not load or their detail should not be updated. Only allow to update detail of those wards which are active.

Comment: Deleted recordrs should not be load..yes we wil take where isActive is true records only.But the problem is when i insert the record with the deleted wardid. There is a problem of primary key violation.I don't know how to write conditions in insert statement for eliminate error.

Comment: Where are the details inserted? In a detail table? Your question does not have sufficient information in order to be answered correctly.

Comment: Are you trying to insert a new Ward?

Comment: No in my wardtable only i have inserted the data in that only i took isActive variable. I will try to make true or false depending upon user if he delete the record i made false otherwise record is in true.

Comment: Please show your queries.

Comment: yeah i shown the query above in my deleted stored procedure

Comment: @OguzOzgul, No deleted record.If we insert new record there is no problem because that is new wardid..but deleted wardid..how to insert re-again..that record is not deleted in my ward table i just made isActive to flase.

Comment: Ok, what I don't understand is, the record is still in the table, it has an Id, say 123, and what operation are you executing when you get the error? Are you trying to insert a new record with the same Id or what? You should update the existing (virtually deleted) ward record with Id 123

Comment: Yes,the record is still in the ward table.Ex: id is 123 that record is deleted. But i made isActive=false in my ward table,the record is now exist in my table. The problem is when i insert with the same id i.e 123 it won't insert again because that is already present in my table.

Comment: so how to overcome this one?i don't want to delete my record permenently.

Comment: You check if a record with the same Id exists, (even with isActive = false), if yes, display a message to the user saying the record has been deleted, ask him if he wants to undelete, and if yes, set isActive = true, or if you dont want to update the deleted record, insert a new one with a new Id.

Comment: how we insert with the new id?if the same id is present in my table? primary key is not allowed to accept. I don't want to update with the exist record. i want to add a new record with the deleted wardid.

Comment: I don't suppose you happen to be using [SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn935015.aspx)?

Comment: No i am using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1):

Your doing too much with your primary key.

Create a real primary key of type uniqueidentifier / long and auto generated if need be.

Wardid should NOT be your primary key for this table, use your business logic to lookup data on this column and update / delete / insert as required. leave the new primary key for use by your database only. If wardid needs to be unique, make it a unique column by adding it to a unique index or use business logic.

Comment: Many would argue that "real primary key" is the opposite of what you're suggesting, which is to add a [*surrogate* key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) to the system - a meaningless but guaranteed unique identifier.

Comment: @uk2k05 : what's the problem if i use my primary key like that. I have a thought of add id column in my table then apply my primary key constraint on(id,wardid) then it allow access to store deleted id.because i will give id as an autoincrement so it allow.In my insert sp i put condition if the wardid is present and isActive is set to false then only i will insert the record.So is this any problem?to our my app?Give your suggestions.

Comment: I am new to SQL server can you give me the detailed explanation of my issue.Is the above process is fine or not?

Answer (score 0):

To add on to [uk2k05's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33828603/80274) an example of how you would implment it would be

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.wardtable
    (
    wardTableId bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    wardid int NOT NULL,
    deletedUniqueifier uniqueidentifier NOT NULL default('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    wmemname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    isActive AS (case when deletedUniqueifier = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' then 1 else 0 end) PERSISTED
    )

ALTER TABLE dbo.wardtable ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_wardtable  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (wardTableId)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UX_wardtable_wardid 
    ON dbo.wardtable (wardid, deletedUniqueifier)
```

Now that isActive is a computed column your update would also have to change to

```sql
update wardtable 
set deletedUniqueifier = newid() 
where wardid = @wardid and deletedUniqueifier = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

One other logical change you will need to do, any forgen keys that link to this table should link using `wardTableId` instead of `wardid`

Comment: can u give me the explantion of this?because i have another table colony.so in that i used wardid as foreign key..According to wardid means if the wardid is present then only i will insert the colony data into colony table. If i have move to primary key as wardTableId instead of wardid then how to restrict the data into colony table.